# What is the requirement for a collection in order that we can put a foreach on it?

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

What is the requirement for a collection in order that we can put a foreach on it in c#? What are the types on which we can put for each?

EDIT 1: Can anybody come up with a sample code of a User Defined Collection on which Foreach is Implemented.

Comment: Read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx. `What is required is that the type of the collection must have a public method called GetEnumerator, and that must return some type that has a public property getter called Current and a public method MoveNext that returns a bool.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`

Edit: there is the wrinkle that if the type has method called GetEnumerator() that returns an IEnumerator then it is also usable in a foreach. see http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Foreach-IEnumerable-IEnumerator-and-Duck-Typing.aspx

Answer (score 3):

What is generally accepted is that you need implementation of `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` but you can read from Eric's post [Following the pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx) that it is not the case as such

> What is required is that the type of the collection must have a public
>   method called GetEnumerator, and that must return some type that has a
>   public property getter called Current and a public method MoveNext
>   that returns a bool.

Answer (score 3):

The only formal requirement is that it has a method called `GetEnumerator()`, which returns *something* which has a `SomeType Current {get;}` property and a `bool MoveNext()` method. Most commonly, however, this is done by implementing the `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` interface. Indeed, it is *expected* that you will implement this interface (the older method was really intended as a pre-generics optimisation), and using the interface will allow consumers to use your collection with things like LINQ and collection-initializers.

In interesting cases, the easiest way of implementing such is via an "iterator block". For example:

```
class Foo : IEnumerable<int> {
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
       yield return 16;
       yield return 12;
       yield return 31;
       // ^^ now imagine the above was a loop over some internal structure -
       // for example an array, list, linked-list, etc, with a "yield return"
       // per item
    }
}
```